# Dealing with multiple observers at one time in angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable

I am new to angular and I am developing a project that does the following:

1. Read the file and save the data in the array.
2. For each element in the array, it will connect to the database and check the information of these elements.
3. For those elements who exists in the database, their information will be written to file.

As indicated above, I have three async calls for which I need to use observers. Problem is that I do not know how to provide data from one observer to another and how to handle this problem. I tried to use callback but it returns that it creates more problems for multiple calls and multiple returns. Can anyone let me know how to handle such case?!

Comment: Can you attach your code to understand the issue ?

Comment: I tried different codes but nothing worked unfortunately. That is why I just explained the problem and seeking for your suggestions.

Comment: I think you're really making it harder than it needs to be, why not just upload the file to your api, and process it from there, then you could simply return a single observable to your UI, which decreases the complexity.

Answer (score 6):

You need to chain your observables, something like this:

```js
this.readFileObservable.pipe(
  map(fileData => this.convertToArray(fileData)),
  switchMap(array => {
    const observables = array.map(element => this.createDBCallObservable(element));

    return merge(...observables);
  }),
  filter(singleResult => !!singleResult),
).subscribe(singleResult => {
  this.writeToAFile(singleResult);
});
```

See this in action on Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6zfwdo

Keep in mind this is a blind reply and there are more cases to be handled probably, like error handling (I just skip empty results with filter above). You should really read more on RxJs operators, it's an extremely powerful tool once you wrap your head around it.

Comment: can you give more details... It will be really help full if you give me example